# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 lagging on ios device

Tags: javascript

I had develop a custom street view connecting the google street view real data using Google Maps JavaScript v3 and i had face lagging issue on ios device but my street view is working well in windows OS and android. Anyone have the idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: The Google Maps version seems to be working, without issues on the iOS 10 release. 

Could you try updating your iOS and see if this is functional?

Comment: i using the latest iOS 10.3.2 and i had try to access this official google website (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-custom-tiles) using my iPad Air 2.
It seem like google Maps JavaScript API not working well on iOS device.

Comment: you can report it to google to solve the issue. )

Comment: Did you find solution to this problem ? I'm also facing same problem. I have used javascript google maps in my Ionic app. It works fine in Android but crashes the app on iOS with this error: Connection::waitForSyncReply: Timed-out while waiting for reply, id = 33